# to get the right media queries to cover phones, tables and regular screens for this widths

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a project and we are gone do a responsive design and use media queries. Now I read [Adaptive Web Design](http://easy-readers.net/books/adaptive-web-design/) by Aaron Gustavson, [Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3 by Ben Frain](http://www.packtpub.com/responsive-web-design-with-html-5-and-css3/book) and other online sites. It's one thing tho I'm still kinda not sure how I'm gone do and thats the media queries for my  selected widths.

We decided to do it twitter bootstrap style (not using it tho) where it snaps into place rather then having it fluid.

3 types
mobile - size?
 
tablet - 980px (both landscape and portrait
screen - 1160px

My question is what media queries should i go with to cover that? I truly appreciate help, this is one of the hardest parts for me.

Comment: see my answer to the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384720/css3-media-queries-what-are-good-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LESS framework](http://lessframework.com/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) both take interesting approaches.

LESSframework targets 4 modes:

- Large - 992px w +
- Tablet - 768px w
- Mobile 1 - 480px w
- Mobile 2 - 320px w

Twitter Bootstrap targets five:

- Large - 1200px w +
- Big - 980px w
- Tablet - 768px w
- Mobile 1 - 480-767px w
- Mobile 2 - < 480px w

I would suggest using one of these (or another) responsive CSS frameworks and/or LESS/SASS in order to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom media query but as a standard device media queries refer to this link :

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Take a Device Agnostic approach to media queries:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Target a range of viewports and have your layout stretch or contract via responsive design to fill the space.

There is an endless stream of devices entering the market with different viewports.  Targeting specific dimensions is a losing game, a more generic approach using viewport ranges is a good tactic.