# CSS 3 Media Queries - What resolutions to support

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

With CSS 3 Media Queries, is there any recommendation as to *what resolutions* we should design for?

Currently, I am separating:

1. visible area greater than or equal to 1140px
2. visible area greater than or equal to 960px
3. visible area below 960px

Any links to articles about this are welcome. Eventually, I am looking for a list of recommended resolutions, though.

Comment: As long as the site works in all realistic situations, it's fine. Usually I just resize my browser window until the website looks bad and then add a new rule that reorganizes it down nicely for that width range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good resolution values to use with media queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384720/what-are-good-resolution-values-to-use-with-media-queries)

Comment: by "visible area", do you mean width or height?

Answer (score 2):

A really nice list of recommended resolutions,

[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

And if you are targeting a specific device,

[Media Query Snippets](http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/)

Hope this helps :)